# 404 when calling ASP.Net Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC app with a Web API controller, I believe i provided the right routes and everything but i still get a 404 error when calling the any API of the controller in Postman

here is how the controller looks:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PetsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPetService _petService;

        public PetsController(IPetService _petService)
        {
            this._petService = _petService;
        }

        [HttpPost("Activation")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Activation(Guid id)
        {
            var serviceResult = await _petService.DeletePet(id);
            return Ok(serviceResult);
        }

        [HttpGet("GetPet/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPet(Guid id)
        {
            var serviceResult = await _petService.GetPetDetails(id);
            return Ok(serviceResult);
        }

        [HttpGet("GetPets/{pageSize}/{pageIndex}/{keyWord}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPets(int pageSize, int pageIndex, string keyWord)
        {
            var serviceResult = await _petService.GetPets(pageSize, pageIndex, keyWord);
            return Ok(serviceResult);
        }

        [HttpPost("SavePet")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SavePet(PetDTO pet)
        {
            var serviceResult = (Object)null;

            if (!pet.Id.HasValue)
                serviceResult = await _petService.CreatePet(pet);
            else
                serviceResult = await _petService.EditPet(pet);

            return Ok(serviceResult);
        }

        [HttpGet("GetPetDues/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPetDues(Guid id)
        {
            var serviceResult = await _petService.GetPetDues(id);
            return Ok(serviceResult);
        }

        [HttpGet("GetPetAppointments/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPetAppointments(Guid id)
        {
            var serviceResult = await _petService.GetPetAppointments(id);
            return Ok(serviceResult);
        }

        [HttpGet("GetPetDiseases/{petId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPetDiseases(Guid petId)
        {
            var serviceResult = await _petService.GetPetDiseases(petId);
            return Ok(serviceResult);
        }
    }
```

Launch settings:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50521",
      "sslPort": 44310
    }
```

and this is an examply on how i call an API in Postman:
http://localhost:50521/api/pets/GetPets/10/0/

I believe I should get a 200 OK but still im getting a 404 error! How can i fix this??

Comment: How do you start the application?

Comment: @Nicola I press on IIS Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route template was not used correctly

```
[HttpGet("GetPets/{pageSize}/{pageIndex}/{keyWord?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPets(int pageSize, int pageIndex, string keyWord = null)
{
    var serviceResult = await _petService.GetPets(pageSize, pageIndex, keyWord);
    return Ok(serviceResult);
}
```

The original route used was missing the template parameters.

In fact all of the shown routes are missing their parameters in the route template.

> ### Route template reference
>
> Tokens within curly braces ({ ... }) define route parameters that are bound if the route is matched. You can
> define more than one route parameter in a route segment, but they must
> be separated by a literal value. For example,
> {controller=Home}{action=Index} isn't a valid route, since there's no
> literal value between {controller} and {action}. These route
> parameters must have a name and may have additional attributes
> specified.
>
> Literal text other than route parameters (for example, {id}) and the
> path separator / must match the text in the URL. Text matching is
> case-insensitive and based on the decoded representation of the URLs
> path. To match a literal route parameter delimiter ({ or }), escape
> the delimiter by repeating the character ({{ or }}).

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out and I fixed it immediately but still i'm getting a 404 error